# Alternating series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 a_n^2$ conv. $\implies$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$ conv.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 a_n^2 $ converges. Does this imply $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n $ converges?

I guess it converges, but I couldn't prove it.

I have tried writing $b_n = na_n$ but it seems that the alternating series test did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz$ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=K}^N (-1)^na_n\right| \leq \left(\sum^N_{n=K} \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum^N_{n=K} n^2a_n^2 \right)^{1/2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, I feel so dumb now I forgot to try using cauchy schwarz.